# Sum rows based on ID

Tags: r

I have two columns with id and value. I am trying to sum all rows with the same ID . I am trying to create this as a separate column without using the aggregate function. Preferably using `base` R as I am trying to create a calculated field in the Radiant app

```
ID    value
456   4
456   5
781   10
781   1
123   5
321   3
123   8
321   12
```

Looking for a result as below

```
ID    total
456   9
456   9
781   11
781   11
123   13
321   15
123   13
321   15
```

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[,total:=sum(value),ID][]` but it should be a duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  We group by 'ID' and then `transmute` to create a new column 'Total' as the `sum` of 'value'.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    transmute(Total=sum(value))
```

---

Or use `ave` from `base R` to get the `sum` of 'value' grouped by 'ID' to `transform` the dataset to create a new column.

```
transform(df1, Total= ave(value, ID, FUN=sum))[-2]
```

Comment: to count each unique instead of sum the FUN can replaced with NROW ?

Comment: @dagan In that case `transmute(Count= n())`

Comment: @dagan Yes, after the `group_by(ID)`, you can use that.  If you need both, `mutate(Total=sum(value), Count=n())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93968/discussion-between-dagan-and-akrun).

Comment: Is this the fastest way to do this?

Comment: @Frank No, it is not

Comment: Know a reference, link, or something I can google to find a faster way?